# Отправить post в Ajax

Tags: ajax

Не могу отправить два значения постом

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

$(".search_button").click(function() {
    var searchString    = $("#search_box").val();
    var data            = 'search='+ searchString;

    var whereString    = $("#where_box").val();
    var data2            = 'where='+ whereString;

    // если searchString не пустая
    if(searchString) {
        // делаем ajax запрос
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "do_search.php",
            data: "data&data2", // ошибка тут, в ajax не силён, как соединить два значения?
            beforeSend: function(html) {
                $("#results").html('');
                $("#searchresults").show();
                $(".word").html(searchString);
           },
           success: function(html){
                $("#results").show();
                $("#results").append(html);
          }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Например, так:

    /* ... */
    data: {key1 : val1, key2 : val2},
    /* ... */

Comment: а у меня как соединить data и data2?

Comment: @Rammsteinik

    var data = {search: searchString, where: whereString};

Comment: data: {"data": data, "data2": data2},

Comment: @Rammsteinik, что значит "соединить"? Может мы о разных вещах говорим? Если передать два значения, то хоть так:

    /* ... */
    data: {data: data, data2 : data2},
    /* ... */

На сервере встречаем: $_POST['data'] и $_POST['data2']. Но имена ключам, я бы всё же давал как-то более осмыслено иначе потом путаница будет, когда до уровня Facebook дойдёте ;)

Comment: Верно, спасибо!